# Using Content-Range file uploading with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I've got an ASP.Net web site that needs to accept large file uploads from a Flex application. It sends the file using the Content-Range to chunk the file it sends. Does ASP.Net have anything in its HttpFileCollection and HttpPostedFile that facilitates handling files posted this way? Is each chunk sent as a new post to the page?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to parse the request using an `IHttpModule` inside of the `BeginRequest` method.

Comment: You should add more details.